# sharing an object between two viewcontrollers in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, uiviewcontroller

I am guessing that this maybe a silly beginner question, but I cant figure out the answer to it. I basically have two view controllers in my iphone app that I would like them to share a third class (.m and .h) that suppose to hold data that both suppose to use. Lets say for example that both views are displaying locations and presenting a table with some of this information manipulated - what i'd like to do is to have a third class, like an engine, that will do all that, and those views will just instantiate this engine and read the table/location data when needed.

My question is - how can I instantiate this engine in both my views but have in fact only one copy of the engine that both views read from. I know that when instantiating twice, two copies are being created, and i dont want that. i am hoping to make this engine "global".

is this possible at all in objective c? what would be the best way to go about that?

Thank you much all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options when it comes to this. Following an MVC approach, you are on the right track in that you should have a single copy of this data (the model). How you get that to your view controllers is up to you. I'll give two ways and you can see which works better in your situation, but there more than ways to do this. Option 1) Create a singleton to house your model/data.  You've probably seen this in the SDK when using stuff like ... = [SomeController sharedInstance]. The two view controllers can just use that shared instace. Option 2) You can instantiate the model somewhere at startup and pass it directly to the view controllers. Whether it's a singleton or not is not their concern. They just know they have access to some data. You can create a property like @property (nonatomic, retain) TheData *theData for each of the view controllers and pass it that way.

Comment: I like the option of instantiate this during startup (say, appDelegate?) and then pass it - but then, how do i "pass" it?

Comment: It's essentially the same as the singleton, but instead of the view controllers themselves calling TheData *theData = [TheData sharedInstance], they have a property to have this assigned to them. The app delegate might be the one to do TheData *theData = [TheData sharedInstance] and you pass theData to your first view controller. That view controller in turn passes it to the next set of controllers, etc.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much, Adrian, though I am not still 100% sure as to the implementation of this. do you have an example you could refer me to pelease? I am not sure I get how do I "pass" the data from the AppDelegate to the next view, etc. Let's say I declare TheData *theData = [TheData sharedInstance] in my AppDelegate - how do I "pass" it to the view controller?

Comment: Your view controller is a regular object so just create @property (nonatomic, retain) TheData *theData in it and your app delegate can do this: theViewController.theData = theData; This might be confusing IF your app delegate is assigning a navigationController from a nib to self.window.rootViewController. In this case, why don't you just move the code from app delegate to the root view controller.

Comment: but if I do that I can only read from that object, and cant write to it in a way that will be reflected everywhere, no?

Comment: If you make sure that TheData is a proper singleton then you can pass it around as you wish and all changes you "write" to it will be reflected everywhere else. This happens because the singleton only lets one instance of that class be created so anyone who calls [TheData sharedInstance] will get the same object b/c it's "shared"

Answer (score 2):

You might consider adding a `@property` to both view controller's that points to your model ("engine") object. When the view controller's are created, you can set that `@property` to point to the model. If the `@property` is `retain`, then it won't copy the model.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one of these "Engines", I'd suggest going the singleton route.

Create a static method that returns an instance to the object you want shared, then you can use that method in each class.

forgive my syntax... I don't have my objective C stuff in front of me atm, but essentially you'll want to do something like the following.

```
EngineClass.h file:

STATIC EngineClass * getSingleton();
STATIC EngineClass * INSTANCE;

EngineClass.m file:
STATIC EngineClass * getSingleton()
{
  if(INSTANCE == null)
  {
      INSTANCE = new EngineClass();
  }
  return INSTANCE;
}
```